# Concurrent Modification exception while accessing Spring bean class

Tags: java, spring

I am having a web application which is running on tomcat server and on java 11. I have a spring bean class like

```
@Component
public class PatternMatcher {

    private Map<String, Pattern> patterns = new HashMap<>();
    String regEx = "(?i)apc\.[A-z]{2}\.011\.[0-9]+\.02.*";

    public boolean isAMatch(String exp){

        return getMatcherPattern().matcher(exp).matches();

    }

    private Pattern getMatcherPattern(){

        return patterns.computeIfAbsent(regex, Pattern::compile);

    }

}
```

This class is injected in some other classes and its working fine in my local and in test environments. But in production, I am seeing intermittent logs like

**java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)**

Is it because multiple requests are accessing the map? If yes will using a ConcurrentHashmap fix the issue? As its not reproducible only in production, I cannot try trial and error. Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because multiple requests are accessing the map?

Yes, it looks like it.

> If yes will using a ConcurrentHashmap fix the issue?

It could be one solution. It just depends what you are actually doing here.

Answer (score 0):

For the code you have shown here, there is no point in having a `Map`.

Avoid the problem entirely by simply compiling the regex once, eagerly, and reuse that:

```
public class PatternMatcher {
    private static final Pattern PATTERN =
        Pattern.compile("(?i)apc\.[A-z]{2}\.011\.[0-9]+\.02.*");

    public boolean isAMatch(String exp) {
        return PATTERN.matcher(exp).matches();
    }
}
```

Of course, this may not be possible because of pertinent details omitted from the question.

Comment: I think that is just a simplification for the purpose of asking this question.

Comment: @Andy Turner I am using a hashmap because I have so many regex, just for simplicity I added only one regex.